# Restore table from .frm and .ibd file?

Tags: import, mariadb, innodb, frm

I've some ibd and frm files. Now I want to import those into mysql database. But its not working. I tried with mysqlfrm but it showing

```
C:\xampp\mysql\data\example>mysqlfrm --diagnostic -vvv users.frm
# WARNING: Cannot generate character set or collation names without the --server option.
# CAUTION: The diagnostic mode is a best-effort parse of the .frm file. As such, it may not identify all of the components of the table correctly. This is especially true for damaged files. It will also not read the default values for the columns and the resulting statement may not be syntactically correct.
# Reading .frm file for users.frm:
# The .frm file is a TABLE.
# Skipping to header at : 2
# General Data from .frm file:
{'IO_SIZE': 86,
 'MYSQL_VERSION_ID': 100334,
 'avg_row_length': 0,
 'charset_low': 0,
 'create_options': 9,
 'db_create_pack': 2,
 'default_charset': 224,
 'default_part_eng': 0,
 'extra_size': 16,
 'frm_file_ver': 5,
 'frm_version': 10,
 'key_block_size': 0,
 'key_info_length': 33,
 'key_length': 505,
 'legacy_db_type': 'INNODB',
 'length': 12831,
 'max_rows': 0,
 'min_rows': 0,
 'rec_length': 11314,
 'row_type': 0,
 'table_charset': 224,
 'tmp_key_length': 505}
# Skipping to key data at : 56
# Reading key part 0.
# Index (key) Data from .frm file:
{'key_names': ['PRIMARY'],
 'keys': [{'algorithm': 0,
           'block_size': 0,
           'comment': '',
           'flags': 0,
           'key_length': 8,
           'key_parts': [{'field_num': 1,
                          'key_part_flag': 0,
                          'key_type': 16896,
                          'length': 8,
                          'offset': 2}],
           'num_parts': 1}],
 'num_key_parts': (1,),
 'num_keys': 1}
# Skipping to default data at : 250
# Skipping to keys at : 2e83
# Engine string: InnoDB
# Partition string:
# Skipping to column data at : 2fb4
{'com_length': 64512,
 'int_length': 0,
 'interval_count': 0,
 'interval_parts': 57352,
 'n_length': 3840,
 'null_fields': 0,
 'num_cols': 20,
 'pos': 3,
 'unknown': 16896}
# Fields per screen = 0
EXCEPTION: unpack requires a string argument of length 1
ERROR: Cannot read column data.
```

I installed mysqlfrm on windows 10. If anyone know how to solve this, Please let me know. that be a great help.  
Thank you

Comment: What MySQL/MariaDB version are the frm/ibd info from and what version are you importing them into (not the xampp version)? Recommend following [official documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-file-per-table-tablespaces/#copying-transportable-tablespaces).

Comment: MariaDB 10.6 engine innodb

Comment: mysqlfrm isn't a tool for MariaDB, hence it failing. Use official documentation on transportable tablespaces.

Comment: okey thanks, but i dont have .cfg file only have .ibd and .frm. in the official documentation you mention earlier included a .cfg file and .ibd

Comment: `FLUSH TABLES test.t1 FOR EXPORT` creates a cfg file

Comment: Thanks I was able to import the data with your help. But now I'm getting another issue,  I'm getting 1.8634250866470974e-307(should be 20.50 small number) huge number its only happening with the data type double, otherwise reset of the data was fine. Any suggestion?

Comment: I attempted what I think you've described [successfully](https://gist.github.com/grooverdan/4c37fb6e5feb2285d2053b50d0db8951). If it was different, can you create a [bug report](http://jira.mariadb.org/) containing a sample table structure and steps.

Comment: plz check the zip file, i attach the schema file and ibd file i got these files from /var/lib/mysql/database  now i'm trying to import this into new database, i follow your link, then was able to import but the data was kinda broken like i told you before, you are a great guy o really apricate your help

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eUH1z7i9RUV66u3QwsdtJ6ohTdNtGZpO/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you shared `users.ibd` and `user.frm` I took a shot and recovered the table on a Windows 11 machine. Actually, on "Ubuntu on Windows", so it will work on native Ubuntu.

First, get [Undrop for InnoDB](https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb) and compile it.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb.git
$ cd undrop-for-innodb/
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install gcc flex bison
$ make
```

Drop `users.zip` in the current directory - `undrop-for-innodb`. Unzip it.

```
unzip users.zip
```

Now let's recover a table schema from users.frm. I like [dbsake](https://dbsake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) tool. It's much better than `mysqlfrm` (sorry Oracle, that's true).

```
$ curl -s http://get.dbsake.net > dbsake
$ chmod u+x dbsake
$ ./dbsake frmdump users.frm > users.sql
```

Here's your schema:

```
$ cat users.sql
--
-- Table structure for table `users`
-- Created with MySQL Version 10.3.34
--

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `balance` double NOT NULL,
  `admin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ref_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `referral` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `notification` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `referral_total` double NOT NULL,
  `life_balance` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `refer_by` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `notice_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `notice_message` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `coupon` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_spent` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_order` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_refund` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `expire_ref` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '90',
  `ref_created` timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Now, let's fetch records from `users.ibd`. First step would be to parse the ibd file and sort InnoDB pages in it.

```
./stream_parser -f users.ibd
```

The `stream_parser` creates `pages-users.ibd/FIL_PAGE_INDEX/0000000000000367.page`. This is a file with InnoDB pages of the `PRIMARY` index of the `users` table. Basically, this is where the table records are.

Second step is to fetch records from `0000000000000367.page`.

```
$ mkdir -p dumps/default
$ ./c_parser -6f pages-users.ibd/FIL_PAGE_INDEX/0000000000000367.page -t users.sql 2> load.sql > dumps/default/users
```

The command saves records in a file `dumps/default/users`

```
$ head dumps/default/users
-- Page id: 3, Format: COMPACT, Records list: Valid, Expected records: (3 3)
-- Page id: 3, Found records: 0, Lost records: YES, Leaf page: NO
-- Page id: 4, Format: COMPACT, Records list: Valid, Expected records: (27 27)
000000000000    80000000000000  users   1       "support"       "admin@saveneur.com"    "8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918"      49939.250000    1       "admin"    "f7315c0bbe5793a0182599b22932d8a77848ab9a0b06e30c37f8be74d058f1c4"      "none"  0       0.000000        56503.250000    NULL    NULL    NULL    ""      8148.250000     1315.00000NULL     "90"    NULL    NULL    "2023-01-10 14:40:02"
000000000000    80000000000000  users   61      "deliveredswiftly@gmail.com"    "deliveredswiftly@gmail.com"    "3c469e9d6c5875d37a43f353d4f88e61fcf812c66eee3457465a40b0da4153e0"      6.500000   0       "65d90fc6d307590b14e9e1800d4e8eab"      "8aaf6d0ff6e5b015c56fa47060b11d877cc6f7e09d6499f161203ccbe4f3056f"      "none"  0       0.000000        110.000000      "none"  """"       "Delivered1"    8455.500000     1088.000000     NULL    "90"    NULL    "2022-09-12 06:03:08"   "2023-01-10 03:34:07"
000000000000    80000000000000  users   62      "Amander11"     "butterphlys11@hotmail.com"     "3c469e9d6c5875d37a43f353d4f88e61fcf812c66eee3457465a40b0da4153e0"      0.000000        0 "3f9e3767ef3b10a0de4c256d7ef9805d"       "1b9588d1fe5cd0ffc3a126c0e53fca995c44bc2884de5c55ad323a9369087951"      "none"  0       0.000000        NULL    "none"  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL       NULL    NULL    "90"    NULL    "2022-09-21 04:47:31"   "2022-09-21 04:47:31"
000000000000    80000000000000  users   63      "Mrbargainbeast"        "mrbargainbeast@gmail.com"      "3c469e9d6c5875d37a43f353d4f88e61fcf812c66eee3457465a40b0da4153e0"      0.000000  "2b38c2df6a49b97f706ec9148ce48d86"       "75530007195799a0d4569a68ff833792039b526cdeb8eb99b05b1c1284e74d6f"      "none"  0       0.000000        NULL    "none"  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL       NULL    NULL    "90"    NULL    "2022-09-21 04:48:38"   "2022-09-21 04:48:38"
000000000000    80000000000000  users   64      "partsofus"     "info@partsofus.com"    "3c469e9d6c5875d37a43f353d4f88e61fcf812c66eee3457465a40b0da4153e0"      0.000000        0       "05ae14d7ae387b93370d142d82220f1b" "36512164c97c2f83df9ccbb395b8446727992fd1482ef24ae369c85d6b890670"      "none"  0       0.000000        NULL    "none"  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL       NULL    "90"    NULL    "2022-09-21 06:33:55"   "2022-09-21 06:33:55"
000000000000    80000000000000  users   65      "Finditforu"    "finditforu@gmail.com"  "3c469e9d6c5875d37a43f353d4f88e61fcf812c66eee3457465a40b0da4153e0"      0.000000        0       "2122c699d5e3d2fa6690771845bd7904" "6e05e801665a5bc864dc9b59154f67a3fcb92283947592a243361afd4a2427c0"      "none"  0       0.000000        NULL    "none"  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL       NULL    "90"    NULL    "2022-09-21 06:52:00"   "2022-09-21 06:52:00"
000000000000    80000000000000  users   66      "VibrantReturns"        "Vibrantreturns@protonmail.com" "3c469e9d6c5875d37a43f353d4f88e61fcf812c66eee3457465a40b0da4153e0"      0.000000  "0c2bcf2ee48c024117f6a057105ead45"       "be1d510e75e07e39d0874d2a971bb61bc1d218288b699289db6b3a7299fdb1c4"      "none"  0       0.000000        NULL    "none"  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL       NULL    NULL    "90"    NULL    "2022-09-21 17:19:56"   "2022-09-21 17:19:56"
```

To load this file into a MySQL instance `c_parser` also generates a helper LOAD  statement which I saved in `load.sql`

```
$ cat load.sql
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/aleks/undrop-for-innodb/dumps/default/users' REPLACE INTO TABLE `users` CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES STARTING BY 'users\t' (`id`, `username`, `email`, `token`, `balance`, `admin`, `ref_id`, `password`, `referral`, `notification`, `referral_total`, `life_balance`, `refer_by`, `notice_type`, `notice_message`, `coupon`, `total_spent`, `total_order`, `total_refund`, `expire_ref`, `ref_created`, `created_at`, `updated_at`);
-- STATUS {"records_expected": 86, "records_dumped": 86, "records_lost": false} STATUS END
```

The load command should be something like

```
mysql my_database < load.sql
```

If you repeat the steps you should get the same result. If something doesn't work - drop me a line in LinkedIn I will send you the `dumps/default/users` file.

Good luck.